# D3 positioning inside div

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a D3.js graph that I want to positioned inside of the 31st day on the calendar. Currently the graph is below the calendar,  even though the  tag is in the proper place.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter275/LYyCp/

```
 <div class="cellDate">31</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="graph.js"></script>
   <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
     <span id="value">100</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I needed to change the d3.select() to the ID of the div.